# how do I control what version of python runs a program?

Tags: python, linux

My machine has 2 versions of python installed, python 2.7.17 and python 3.6.9

I have this program that has the shebang line

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

If I do:

```
 python --version
```

then it will return 2.7.17.

However, sometimes (it doesnt happen all the time), when i run this program , it runs as 3.6.9.

Someone please help me fix this hot mess

Comment: does python3 (nameoffile).py work

Comment: Your IDE might support changing your interpreter, if you use pyCharm change that supports changing your python version

Comment: It's not clear how to run `that.py` file. There should be environmental difference while you getting 2.7.17 or 3.6.9. Please enlighten this part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your shebang is using the full path to the executable. Which could be different from the python found on your path.

First you might want to check if the python found in your path matches the shebang path:

> which python

This will output the path. I would expect it to be different.

If you run:

> /usr/bin/python --version

This will tell you what version is being used by your script.

Hopefully that will give you a better idea of which python executable is used when.

You might find that using python virtual environments will give you a more control over versions and packages.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu there are two versions of Python installed, Python2 and Python3. This is because both versions are used by Ubuntu operation system. In order to see which versions are on your system run the command:

$ ls -alh /usr/bin | grep python

If you run the command above you will see that python is a link (in your case it is a link to python 2.7.17). When you are running the command

$ which python

you are asking which version of python /usr/bin/python links to.

The amazing thing is that you can install all versions of Python on your machine, and you can create and run the projects with the version of your choice! If you are interested check the the pyenv project: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv. It helps with Python versions management, and you can explicitly tell which version of Python you want to use for a particular project directory. (I totally love it).